# ANOVA Stats Computation in Spark 2 with Java 8

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, anova

I have a piece of code in Java 8 in order to compute Annova statistics by using Spark SQL API as shown in the **SNIPPET 1** below. This code segment is tailored based on the original SCALA code available at https://gist.github.com/srnghn/c74835818802fefabd76f1bcd6746831/77690607caab9039b015d2232c1216500427a995

**QUESTION**

When I run this as a spark job I am getting the error that is indicated in the **SNIPPET 2** below where the problem occurs in the dataFrame named **"joined"**. The part where error occurs has been marked with a comment " //!!!! VARIABLE UNDER QUESTION AS FOLLOWS !!!!" in **SNIPPET 1** below. Following the definition of this variable, namely **"joined"**, I have provided the original SCALA version from above indicated URL. Could you please point out what I am missing in the Java version? Thanks.

**The essence of the problem has been highlighted in bold in the following text:**

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: **cannot resolve '`c.sum(valueSq))`'** given input columns: [b.sum(value), d.cat, a.count, c.cat, c.sum(valueSq), b.cat, d.avg(value), a.cat];;
'Project [cat#51, count#74L, sum(value)#70, 'c.sum(valueSq)), 'avg(value))]

**SNIPPET 1:**

```
private static AnovaStats computeAnovaStats(SparkSession spark, Dataset<Row> outliersDF){
    outliersDF.createOrReplaceTempView("outliersDF");
    Dataset<Row> anovaBaseDF =
            spark.sql("SELECT usercode as cat, cast((frequency) as double) as value FROM outliersDF");

    anovaBaseDF.createOrReplaceTempView("anovaBaseDF");
    Dataset<Row> newDF =
            spark.sql(
                      "SELECT " +
                            "A.cat, A.value, " +
                            "cast((A.value * A.value) as double) as valueSq, " +
                            "((A.value - B.avg) * (A.value - B.avg)) as diffSq " +
                            "FROM anovaBaseDF A " +
                            "JOIN " +
                            "(SELECT cat, avg(value) as avg FROM anovaBaseDF GROUP BY cat) B " +
                            "WHERE A.cat = B.cat");

    RelationalGroupedDataset grouped = newDF.groupBy("cat");
    Dataset<Row> sums = grouped.sum("value");
    Dataset<Row> counts = grouped.count();
    long numCats = counts.count();
    Dataset<Row> sumsq = grouped.sum("valueSq");
    Dataset<Row> avgs = grouped.avg("value");

    double totN = toDouble(counts.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("count")).first().get(0));
    double totSum = toDouble(sums.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("sum(value)")).first().get(0));
    double totSumSq = toDouble(sumsq.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("sum(valueSq)")).first().get(0));

    double totMean = totSum / totN;
    double dft = totN - 1;
    double dfb = numCats - 1;
    double dfw = totN - numCats;

    //!!!! VARIABLE UNDER QUESTION IS AS FOLLOWS !!!!
    Dataset<Row> joined =
            (counts.as("a")
                    .join(sums.as("b"), (col("a.cat").$eq$eq$eq(col("b.cat"))))
                    .join(sumsq.as("c"), (col("a.cat").$eq$eq$eq(col("c.cat"))))
                    .join(avgs.as("d"), (col("a.cat").$eq$eq$eq(col("d.cat"))))
                    .select(col("a.cat"), col("count"), col("sum(value)"),
                            col("sum(valueSq))"), col("avg(value))")));

 /*
 The original SCALA version of the local variable "joined", which is of type 
 "Dataset<Row>", is as follows:

 val joined = (counts.as("a").join(sums.as("b"), $"a.cat" === 
 $"b.cat")).join(sumsq.as("c"),$"a.cat" === 
 $"c.cat").join(avgs.as("d"),$"a.cat"===$"d.cat").select($"a.cat",$"count",$"sum(value)",$"sum(valueSq)",$"avg(value)")
 */

    Dataset<Row> finaldf = joined.withColumn("totMean", lit(totMean));

    JavaPairRDD<String, Double> ssb_tmp =
            finaldf.javaRDD()
                    .mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2(x.getString(0), ((toDouble(x.get(4)) - toDouble(x.get(4))) * (toDouble(x.get(5)) * toDouble(x.get(4)) - toDouble(x.get(4)) * toDouble(x.get(1))))));

    Dataset<Row> ssbDR = spark.sqlContext().createDataset(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(ssb_tmp), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.DOUBLE())).toDF();
    double ssb = ssbDR.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("_2")).first().getDouble(0);

    Dataset<Row> ssw_tmp = grouped.sum("diffSq");
    double ssw = toDouble(ssw_tmp.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("sum(diffSq)")).first().get(0));

    double sst = ssb + ssw;
    double msb = ssb / dfb;
    double msw = ssw / dfw;
    double fValue = msb / msw;
    double etaSq = ssb / sst;
    double omegaSq = (ssb - ((numCats - 1) * msw))/(sst + msw);

    AnovaStats anovaStats = new AnovaStats(dfb, dfw, fValue, etaSq, omegaSq);
    return anovaStats;
}

private static double toDouble(Object value){
    double retVal = 0d;
    if(value instanceof  Double){
        retVal = ((Double) value).doubleValue();
    } else if (value instanceof Long){
        retVal = ((Long) value).doubleValue();
    } else if (value == null){
        retVal = 0d;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

**SNIPPET 2:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`c.sum(valueSq))`' given input columns: [b.sum(value), d.cat, a.count, c.cat, c.sum(valueSq), b.cat, d.avg(value), a.cat];;
'Project [cat#51, count#74L, sum(value)#70, 'c.sum(valueSq)), 'avg(value))]
+- AnalysisBarrier
      +- Join Inner, (cat#51 = cat#175)
         :- Join Inner, (cat#51 = cat#154)
         :  :- Join Inner, (cat#51 = cat#139)
         :  :  :- SubqueryAlias a
         :  :  :  +- Aggregate [cat#51], [cat#51, count(1) AS count#74L]
         :  :  :     +- Project [cat#51, value#52, cast((value#52 * value#52) as double) AS valueSq#56, ((value#52 - avg#55) * (value#52 - avg#55)) AS diffSq#57]
         :  :  :        +- Filter (cat#51 = cat#59)
         :  :  :           +- Join Inner
         :  :  :              :- SubqueryAlias A
         :  :  :              :  +- SubqueryAlias anovabasedf
         :  :  :              :     +- Project [usercode#10 AS cat#51, cast(frequency#0L as double) AS value#52]
         :  :  :              :        +- SubqueryAlias outliersdf
         :  :  :              :           +- Filter ((cast(frequency#0L as double) >= -718.5) && (cast(frequency#0L as double) <= 1413.5))
         :  :  :              :              +- Project [flowId#6, StateId#9, usercode#10, frequency#0L]
         :  :  :              :                 +- Filter (frequency#0L > cast(30 as bigint))
         :  :  :              :                    +- SubqueryAlias T
         :  :  :              :                       +- SubqueryAlias basedf
         :  :  :              :                          +- Project [flowId#6, StateId#9, usercode#10, frequency#0L]
         :  :  :              :                             +- Sort [flowId#6 ASC NULLS FIRST, StateId#9 ASC NULLS FIRST, usercode#10 ASC NULLS FIRST], true
         :  :  :              :                                +- Aggregate [flowId#6, StateId#9, usercode#10], [flowId#6, StateId#9, usercode#10, count(instanceuserid#25) AS frequency#0L]
```

Comment: Typo `sum(valueSq)` not `sum(valueSq))`. Same `avg(value)` not `avg(value))`.. Also `Column` has dedicated Java  methods so `col("a.cat").$eq$eq$eq(col("b.cat"))` can be `col("a.cat").equalTo(col("b.cat"))`.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo mistake as indicated in the comment (i.e. sum(valueSq) not sum(valueSq)). Same avg(value) not avg(value))). The working solution is as follows:

```
private static AnovaStats computeAnovaStats(SparkSession spark, Dataset<Row> outliersDF, int flowId){
    outliersDF.createOrReplaceTempView("outliersDF");
    Dataset<Row> anovaBaseDF =
            spark.sql("SELECT usercode as cat, cast((frequency) as double) as value FROM outliersDF");

    anovaBaseDF.createOrReplaceTempView("anovaBaseDF");
    Dataset<Row> newDF =
            spark.sql(
                      "SELECT " +
                            "A.cat, A.value, " +
                            "cast((A.value * A.value) as double) as valueSq, " +
                            "((A.value - B.avg) * (A.value - B.avg)) as diffSq " +
                            "FROM anovaBaseDF A " +
                            "JOIN " +
                            "(SELECT cat, avg(value) as avg FROM anovaBaseDF GROUP BY cat) B " +
                            "WHERE A.cat = B.cat");

    RelationalGroupedDataset grouped = newDF.groupBy("cat");
    Dataset<Row> sums = grouped.sum("value");
    Dataset<Row> counts = grouped.count();
    long numCats = counts.count();
    Dataset<Row> sumsq = grouped.sum("valueSq");
    Dataset<Row> avgs = grouped.avg("value");

    double totN = toDouble(counts.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("count")).first().get(0));
    double totSum = toDouble(sums.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("sum(value)")).first().get(0));
    double totSumSq = toDouble(sumsq.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("sum(valueSq)")).first().get(0));

    double totMean = totSum / totN;
    double dft = totN - 1;
    double dfb = numCats - 1;
    double dfw = totN - numCats;

    Dataset<Row> joined =
            (counts.as("a")
                    .join(sums.as("b"), (col("a.cat").equalTo(col("b.cat"))))
                    .join(sumsq.as("c"), (col("a.cat").equalTo(col("c.cat"))))
                    .join(avgs.as("d"), (col("a.cat").equalTo(col("d.cat"))))
                    .select(col("a.cat"), col("count"), col("sum(value)"),
                            col("sum(valueSq)"), col("avg(value)")));

    Dataset<Row> finaldf = joined.withColumn("totMean", lit(totMean));

    JavaPairRDD<String, Double> ssb_tmp =
            finaldf.javaRDD()
                    .mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2(x.getString(0), ((toDouble(x.get(4)) - toDouble(x.get(4))) * (toDouble(x.get(5)) * toDouble(x.get(4)) - toDouble(x.get(4)) * toDouble(x.get(1))))));

    Dataset<Row> ssbDR = spark.sqlContext().createDataset(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(ssb_tmp), Encoders.tuple(Encoders.STRING(),Encoders.DOUBLE())).toDF();
    double ssb = ssbDR.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("_2")).first().getDouble(0);

    Dataset<Row> ssw_tmp = grouped.sum("diffSq");
    double ssw = toDouble(ssw_tmp.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum("sum(diffSq)")).first().get(0));

    double sst = ssb + ssw;
    double msb = ssb / dfb;
    double msw = ssw / dfw;
    double fValue = msb / msw;
    double etaSq = ssb / sst;
    double omegaSq = (ssb - ((numCats - 1) * msw))/(sst + msw);

    AnovaStats anovaStats = new AnovaStats(dfb, dfw, fValue, etaSq, omegaSq, flowId);
    return anovaStats;
}
```